# Сериализация/Десиалиризация ObservableCollection массив в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, сериализация, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

Прошу вашей помощи, эта вещь не сложна, но до меня совсем не доходит.
Если кратко, то:

```
 public class Class1 : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<Class2> Element1 = new ObservableCollection<Class2>();
        public static ObservableCollection<Class2> Element2 = new ObservableCollection<Class2>();
        public static ObservableCollection<Class2> Element3 = new ObservableCollection<Class2>();
        public static ObservableCollection<Class2> Element4 = new ObservableCollection<Class2>();
        public static ObservableCollection<Class2>[] ArrayElements = new ObservableCollection<Class2>[] { Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4 };

        public void Adding(in string name, in string color, in string car, in int Ind)//вызывается в другом классе при нажатии на кнопку и передаются значения
        {
            ArrayElements[Ind].Add(new Class2()
            {
                Name = name,
                Color = color,
                Car = car,
            });
        }
    }
    public class Class2: BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Car { get; set; }
    }
```

Xamarin   XAML с C#    (потом эти данные переносятся в CollectionView и дальше понятно, что образуется 4 элемента каждый с 3 компонентами)

Нужно любым способом(не важно каким( имею ввиду json или xml или другой какой-то штукой)) сериализировать и дисериализировать массив ObservableCollection. Четвёртый день с утра до ночи думаю, читаю, смотрю как это сделать - не понимаю. Помогите начинающему программисту пожалуйста, если сможете, если не слишком сложно для Вас будет - напишите код. Просто я, либо сильно туплю, либо очень сильно туплю, просто не понимаю, не доходит до моей пустой грёбаной головы как это сделать: при выходе из приложения и обратно заходе эти коллекции сохранялись и сохранялись все 4 ObservableCollection в один ObservableCollection Массив[].

Comment: Пишем в любимом поисковике `c# json сериализация`, в первых ссылках видим [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to), где прям выделено и пошагово сказано что и как, одна строка `string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);` в которую передаются данные... Что тут не понятного может быть, извините, но не пойму... И да, `static` у вас быть не должно (значит что-то делаете не так), как и не должно быть сериализаци ViewModel слоев, ибо за данные отвечает Model слой (если вы делаете по MVVM все).

Comment: Уберите `static`.